# Flexslider 'Next' click event on a radio button

Tags: javascript, onclick, radio-button, flexslider

Im using flexslider to rotate between a set of questions in a form. I would like to create a custom click event, so when a user clicks one of the radio buttons within the form it then proceeds to the next slide.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Although very rudimentary, I created a simple click event on radio types which then clicks the nav-next button.

It works, but there's probably a better way of doing this... Im open to suggestions.

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
$('.flex-next').click();
});
```